# The question "Check if element exists in jQuery" is really popular, but it's both a duplicate and a typographical error

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

A few weeks back I raised a flag on the question [Check if element exists in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery), stating:

> This should be closed and locked. It was previously closed as a duplicate but reopened with 5 reopen votes. It's both a duplicate and a simple typographical error.

The flag was declined, however, with:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I feel this does require moderator intervention as I believe the post should be locked - as I mentioned in my flag text.

This question was originally closed back in 2012 as a duplicate of this: [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery), but for whatever reason was voted to be reopened 10 months later.

This question is both a duplicate of the above question **and** a simple typographical error. The reason it didn't work for OP is because they missed the `#` character - literally that. OP already knew the solution, but failed to implement it because of a simple typo. Despite this, this question has accumulated OP over 2,000 reputation. I feel it's only been rated so high because of the wording of it's title.

I voted to close this question when I raised the flag for it, but for whatever reason my close vote doesn't appear to have made it into the count. When I try to vote to close it again, I'm told that I already voted to close the question.

Can this question please be closed and locked to prevent it from being reopened again?

Comment: On its way to get closed again...

Comment: See, this is what I don't understand. I have an answer to another typo question that has also since garnered hundreds of votes. Did hundreds of people *really* completely disregard the typo when voting on these questions and their answers? Or did they all upvote the posts just to spite the OP *for* the typo? If it is the former, perhaps the community is better served by simply removing the typo altogether since it's clear that nobody actually cares that the question is originally about a typo, but doing that would require all the answers to either be updated or removed as obsolete.

Comment: Or did hundreds of people upvote because they *all* had the exact same typo as the OP? If so, does that mean the question shouldn't be closed despite being about a typo, because it's somehow useful to future readers?

Comment: "OMG! I had this exact typo and completely failed to read any documentation on selectors, ever!" *upvote*

Comment: It is unfortunate that question was closed as a duplicate again. To me, it is not a dupe, only a typo. The questioner was well-aware of the use of `length` in this context, and the crux of the question is the typo, not the methodology used. IMHO it should be reopened then closed as a "simple typographical error". I can use Mjölnir to do the former, but need four other users to do the latter, so I won't do anything (for now).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - My reasoning was that the popularity and the title - what people will see and find when they search - would be enough for marking as a duplicate but.. well. You're probably more right about typo being a more valid close reason. As long as it's closed, in my book. It's useless either way. =/

Comment: @BoltClock "Or did hundreds of people upvote because they all had the exact same typo as the OP?" That would be my guess. (I've had the exact same typo.)